# Upload an image to twitter profile header using PHP and twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

Few months ago twitter launched new profile design where you can have a profile header image like facebook have.

I know it is possible to upload an image using there API. I searched everywhere but I coudn't find how to do this.

Exactly what I want to do this: if there is an image in my server I just want to upload it to twitter header image using php.

If anyone knows a way to do this please let me know. Thanks in advance.